# Modify capabilities in watson virtual agent

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-virtual-agent

I'm evaluating Watson Virtual Agent, but for Spanish, I see that all the capabilities are "closed" in the sense that cannot include any other sentence for a specific capability.

Using conversations component, during the testing that can be done not programmatically but visually. That feature cannot see it in WVA. Is there any plan for including that?

Thanks, Manuel

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I follow. 
If you create intents/entities/dialogs in conversation, you can utilize them through WVA by connecting your workspace to use custom capabilities.

You are correct that you cannot add your custom capabilities to an existing WVA skill. I would recommend turning off the WVA skill and connecting your custom workspace so you have full control.

Comment: Thanks Mitch for you answer. I was asking for the posibility of modyfing existing skills in WVA including new intents, for example. I think it could be something interesing to get into.

Comment: Unfortunately they are by reference only, so you can't edit them.